# Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "pch"

Tags: r, visualization, dbscan

I have applied DBSCAN algorithm on built-in dataset iris in R. But I am getting error when tried to visualise the output using the plot( ).

Following is my code.

```
library(fpc)
library(dbscan)


data("iris")
head(iris,2)


data1 <- iris[,1:4]
head(data1,2)

set.seed(220)
db <- dbscan(data1,eps = 0.45,minPts = 5)

table(db$cluster,iris$Species)

plot(db,data1,main = 'DBSCAN')
```

> Error: Error in axis(side = side, at = at, labels = labels, ...) :
> invalid value specified for graphical parameter "pch"

How to rectify this error?

Comment: you need to use [`fpc::dbscan`](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/wiki.php?id_contents=7940#r-functions-for-dbscan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a suggestion below, but first I see two issues:

1. You're loading two packages, `fpc` and `dbscan`, both of which have *different* functions named `dbscan()`. This could create tricky bugs later (e.g. if you change the order in which you load the packages, different functions will be run).
2. It's not clear what you're trying to plot, either what the x- or y-axes should be or the type of plot. The function `plot()` generally takes a vector of values for the x-axis and another for the y-axis (although not always, consult `?plot`), but here you're passing it a `data.frame` and a `dbscan` object, and it doesn't know how to handle it.

Here's one way of approaching it, using `ggplot()` to make a scatterplot, and `dplyr` for some convenience functions:

```
# load our packages
# note: only loading dbscacn, not loading fpc since we're not using it
library(dbscan)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# run dbscan::dbscan() on the first four columns of iris
db <- dbscan::dbscan(iris[,1:4],eps = 0.45,minPts = 5)

# create a new data frame by binding the derived clusters to the original data
# this keeps our input and output in the same dataframe for ease of reference
data2 <- bind_cols(iris, cluster = factor(db$cluster))

# make a table to confirm it gives the same results as the original code
table(data2$cluster, data2$Species)

# using ggplot, make a point plot with "jitter" so each point is visible
# x-axis is species, y-axis is cluster, also coloured according to cluster
ggplot(data2) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=Species, y = cluster, colour = cluster),
             position = "jitter") +
  labs(title = "DBSCAN")
```

Here's the image it generates:

[image: A scatterplot generated using ggplot() showing species of iris clustered by the function dbscan::dbscan()]

If you're looking for something else, please be more specific about what the final plot should look like.

Comment: `It's not clear what you're trying to plot` that's why you should check the class of the first argument to `plot`

Comment: @Christopher Belanger I just wanted to plot the cluster and you interpreted right. Thank you.